# Nested subplot do not align well in PowerBI Deneb

Tags: alignment, vega-lite, deneb

I tried to make a nested scatter chart using Deneb in PowerBI [(Sample Chart)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2Hb4.png), I found that the subplot size will follow the maximum subplot (in this example, subplot B has 4 weather types and subplot A has 3).

I tried `"align" : "none"` but it did not work,
I would like to know if there's anyway to format the chart even if the facet column is not the same, in this example, remove the red frame.

[source code](https://github.com/ChiaLingWeng/Variability-Gauge-PowerBI-Script/tree/main)

```
{
    "data": {
        "name": "dataset"
    },
    "vconcat": [
        {
            "facet": {
                "column": {
                    "field": "opid",
                    "header": {
                        "title": "",
                        "labelOrient": "bottom",
                        "labelExpr": "null"
                    },
                    "title": null
                },
                "align": "none"
            },
            "spec": {
                "facet": {
                    "column": {
                        "field": "sky",
                        "header": {
                            "title": "",
                            "labelOrient": "bottom"
                        },
                        "title": null
                    }
                },
                "spec": {
                    "layer": [
                        {
                            "mark": {
                                "type": "point",
                                "tooltip": true
                            },
                            "encoding": {
                                "x": {
                                    "field": "state",
                                    "type": "nominal",
                                    "title": ""
                                },
                                "y": {
                                    "field": "birds_seen",
                                    "type": "quantitative"
                                },
                                "color": {
                                    "field": "species",
                                    "type": "nominal",
                                    "scale": {
                                        "scheme": "pbiColorNominal"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "params": [
                                {
                                    "name": "_pan_and_zoom",
                                    "select": "interval",
                                    "bind": "scales"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```